# Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. when using db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

When looping through database rows and editing data with each iteration using the following code

```
 var entities = db.entities.Where(l => l.id > 28181 && l.id < 28425 && l.Geometry == null).ToList();
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        foreach (model entity in entities)
        {

            string area = entity.address + " " + entity.city + " " + country;
            var address = String.Format("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=AIzaSyArOWaWq_xXjAm68DlFFFqoxK7Z_ggYk9E&address=" + gebied);
            response = await client.GetAsync(address);
            var bekijk = response.StatusCode;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var jObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(data.Result);
                string status = jObject["status"].ToObject<string>();
                if (status== "OK")
                {
                    var geometryLocation = jObject["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"];
                    string lat = geometryLocation["lat"].ToObject<string>();
                    string lon = geometryLocation["lng"].ToObject<string>();
                    entity.Geometry = System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeometry.FromText("POINT(" + lat + " " + lon + ")");
                    entity.Latitude = Convert.ToDecimal(lat.Replace('.', ','));
                    entity.Longitude = Convert.ToDecimal(lon.Replace('.', ','));
                    db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }

            }

        }
        db.SaveChanges();
```

At `db.SaveChanges();` an error occurs. Namely

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

I've tried the solutions I saw on stackoverflow but nothing did the trick. Does anyone have any clues? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error usually occurs when Entity Framework cannot find entity with the same `id` to update

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. Should this line `foreach (kandidaten kandidaat in kandidaten)` be this instead: `foreach (Entity entity in entities)` ?

Comment: I believe you Adil Mammadov, but when I set a breakpoint in the loop, I see the id is there. So how come no PK is found?

Comment: Are you setting global "AsNoTracking()" etc on your context? Your error is because the entities tracked by the context don't detect any changes and thus the update doesn't effect any entities.

Comment: is id the only key of this type?

Comment: @Wurd: this is not the reason. The reason for this exception is: there are some entries with the state set to modified/deleted, however ExecuteNonQuery() of DMBS returned 0. That means the objects could not be written, probably because part of the key was modified.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro, the entities stated as changed/modified when written to the db produce zero updated rows => the entities tracked as changed do not produce an update in the database => the entities tracked aren't changed or are already identical in the db. Most likely out of those two are the entities tracked aren't changed.

Comment: @Wurd the entities tracked aren't changed or are already identical in the db. <- this would still result in the update statement to count the effected rows, as Update statement does not select before. The only way the update statement would return 0 would be if the where clause actually returns 0 rows.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assigning the values and saving it in a different method somehow fixes it. 
Can someone please tell me why?

```
    public async void FirstMethod()
    {

        var entities = db.entities.ToList();

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {

            string area= entity.address + " " + entity.city + " " + land;
            var address = String.Format("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=AIzaSyArOWaWq_xXjAm68DlFFFqoxK7Z_ggYk9E&address=" + area);
            response = await client.GetAsync(address);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var jObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(data.Result);
                string status = jObject["status"].ToObject<string>();

                if (status == "OK")
                {
                    var geometryLocation = jObject["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"];
                    string lat = geometryLocation["lat"].ToObject<string>();
                    string lon = geometryLocation["lng"].ToObject<string>();
                    SecondMethod(lat+" "+lon ,entity);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public void SecondMethod(string preometry, model entity)
    {
        entity.Geometry = System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeometry.FromText("POINT(" + preometry + ")");
        string[] latLon = preometry.Split(' ');
        entity.Latitude = Decimal.Parse(latLon[0].Replace(".", ","));
        entity.Longitude = Decimal.Parse(latLon[1].Replace(".", ","));
        db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to update the entities manually?

Using the Package Manager Console:

```
PM> Add-Migration MyMigration
...
PM> Update-Database
```

This may help: [Automatic Code First Migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj554735.aspx)

Comment: Our project is DB first. Updated the model from DB and ran it again but still no difference

Comment: Try to save the changes for each record and see if it happens to a specifc one or with all of them.
The result from this request is returning data?
See if this helps you:
`if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}`